# Use a ListView, or inflate and add views manually?

Tags: android, listview, inflate

Which method is better?
1) Using a listview
2) Inflating and adding views in somelayout manually

Comment: That very much depends on what you are trying to do. In most cases a listview is going to be the best option. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: In my case, I have to add different type of objects in list like videos, offers, articles etc. And I also need some randomness means mixture of these objects. So what would be the best by implementation point of view and efficiency as well?

Comment: Actually I have three arraylists of videos, offers and articles. I have pattern like 2 vidoes, 2 articles and 1 offer. But I have seen that listview works on only one arraylist. So what should I do?
 Also these objects have images. How to load them so that they do not stuck the UI while downloading images?

Comment: I edited the title of the question to be more descriptive of the problem. @Khawar Raza, I think it would be good if you edited your question; add the information that is now in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO: 
Use a listview.

Because 
1) Listviews are standardised Android UI elements. They are recogniced by users as such, and used by developers that know how to use them. If any of them then has to maintain your code, (s)he'll thank you.

2) With some personal experience: Down the road of doing this manually: Lies pain and madness of the worst sort. Just use the tools avilable and save yourself the headache. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It deppends on what you want to do...

If your layout will be like a listview, make a listview with your custom adapters, more optimal and fast ;)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use case, though adding views dynamically is going to be slower, also avoid deeper layout hierarchies.
For list view use ViewHolder to hold the views.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your list to be customized or to have different look and feel than the android inbuilt list, then you can go for inflating and adding views in some layout manually. But efficiency wise , you can go with inbuilt one.

This is help you to know the things more better.

http://www.technotalkative.com/category/android/listview/